# Kismet/Aircrack: why is signal strength negative and what is max reading for?

Tags: wireless-networking

In Kismet, I see that the *signal strength for a particular access-point is -85dBm* and m**ax is at -74dBm**. What does this imply? Why is signal strength negative? I guess the *'m'* is milli-watt but what is the max reading for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874852/what-is-meaning-of-negative-dbm-in-signal-strength

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because decibels are logarithms, and logarithms can be negative. In other words, -85dBm (a very weak signal!!) is about 3 billionths of a milliWatt.

The exact formula is:

signal strength in dBm = 10 log_base_10 (P/ 1 milli Watt).

A signal of -74dBm is about 10 times larger, and so on. A signal of 1 milli Watt, omnidirectional, is implausibly large for telecommunications (pcs, cell phones), so you must expect signal strengths in dBm to be just about always negative.

Hence, the smaller the (absolute) value, the more powerful the signal: -74dBm is stronger -85dBm.